# Switch to handle two inputs and switch between two sets of two outputs (guitar amp send and return switch)

Tags: switches, guitar-pedal, guitar-amplifier

I am looking to build a simple box, for fun, to switch the send and return signals from a guitar amplifier effects loop between two different amplifiers, depending on which amp I am using at the time.

The box would have two 1/4 inch TS input jacks (one for send one for return; these would be connected to the guitar pedals).
It would then have four total output jacks (send and return to amp A, send and return for amp B; these would be connected to the amplifiers' effects loops).

The external connections would be made with standard 1/4 inch instrument cables.
Hopefully that all makes sense - I am obviously new to this.

I would like to be able to have a single switch that would route the input signals to either output A or output B.

What kind of switch can manage this? Or do I need to do something with multiple switches to turn each output on/off?

Any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a double pole (switch both signal and the return), double throw (1 input to 2 outputs) switch. Usually, These are shortened to DPDT.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am struggling to understand how I would wire that, since I'll end up with 4 wires coming in from the 2 inputs, and 8 to go out to the 4 outputs. I've used both SPST and DPDT switches in some guitar wiring setups, but I can't grasp how to manage all of the connections for this setup.

Comment: @jlbriggs: You only have to switch the signal lines. Just connect all the grounds (jack sleeves) together - no need to switch them.

Comment: @PeterBennett I think I get it now, but not 100%. I would wire the sleeve of the single send directly to both of the sleeves on switchable side? And same for the returns?
And then wire the tip of the single send to the center lug of the switch, and the tip of the single return to the other center lug of the switch?
And then the switchable send/return tips to each of the respective outer lugs?
I made a diagram of what I am picturing now here: https://i.imgur.com/VyDDuoJ.png

Comment: @jlbriggs: Your drawing looks fine to me.

Comment: Thank you both. I was overthinking what I needed to do!